# When giving a template parameter a default argument, VS 2017 cannot find previously defined types properly

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-studio-2017

The following code:

```
namespace N {
    template <typename A, typename B = A>
    class Foo;
}

template <typename C, typename D>
class N::Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
};

int main()
{
    N::Foo<char> foo;
}
```

involves a (forward) declaration of the class template `Foo` inside namespace `N`
with two type parameters (`A` and `B`). The (forward) declaration gives the second parameter a default value which is identical to the first parameter (`A`). Later, this class is defined with its parameters differently named (`C` and `D`). Since it is already specified, the default is not given.

This compiles in GCC 7.1 and Clang 3.8 (in C++17 mode) except that the unused variable `foo` is warned. However, VS 2017 15.7.5 (in C++17 mode) says `A` is undefined identifier, and says it is not a valid type name for parameter `D`.

To my surprise, when I changed the code into this:

```
namespace N {
    template <typename A, typename B = C> //note: A changed into C
    class Foo;
}

template <typename C, typename D>
class N::Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
};

int main()
{
    N::Foo<char> foo;
}
```

VS accepts it! (It does not compile in GCC or Clang, though)

I think VS is wrong here. It tries to interpret the default argument in a different context (in this specific case, the definition of `Foo`) whereas GCC and Clang don't. At which step was I wrong? Or is this a bug of VS?

Any help will be appreciated.

(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this is definitely a compiler bug. Using the name of a previous template parameter in the default argument of a subsequent parameter is common practice, the standard library itself does it all over the place (e.g., allocators and comparison functions for standard containers). The standard even explicitly mentions this possibility in a note in [[basic.scope.temp] §3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.temp#3).

VS 2015 seems to be affected too. Note that the template doesn't even have to be in another namespace. I stripped down your example a bit further:

```
template <typename A, typename B = A>
struct S;

template <typename C, typename D>
struct S {};

int main()
{
    S<int> s;
}
```

and this seems to already trigger the issue…

Comment: Thank you. Now I am confident this is a bug :)

Comment: Let me know if you report the bug.

Comment: I have found my way to report it :P

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
namespace N {
    template <typename A, typename B = A>
    class Foo;
}

template <typename A, typename B> //A and B is TYPE
class N::Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
};

int main()
{
    N::Foo<char> foo;
}
```

You can check the reason in the webpage:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/templates-cpp

> T is a template parameter; the typename keyword says that this
>   parameter is a placeholder for a type. When the function is called,
>   the compiler will **replace every instance of T** with the concrete type
>   argument that is either specified by the user or deduced by the
>   compiler.

For example, **it must be an error** if you write a code like:

```
double example(double,int);

int main()
{
//...
}

double example(double a,double b)
{
//...
}
```

because the TYPE you specified conflicts with the prototype.

(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: But here, the parameter is itself a **type**, I am just changing the *name* of it. **It must not be an error** if you write this: `double example(double a, int b); /*...*/ double example(double c, int d);` right? Nothing conflicts.

Comment: You’ve changed the type, not the parameter, so the compiler gives error.

Comment: @L.F. TYPE is not the same as formal parameter. ‘A’ in ‘template<typename A>’ is a placeholder for a type, not a parameter. Read the webpage shown in my answer.

Comment: IMO The equivalent of `template<typename A, typename B> class Foo; /*...*/ template <typename C, typename D> class Foo;` is `double example(double a, int b); /*...*/ double example(double c, int d);`, while the equivalent of `double example(double a, int b); /*...*/ double example(double a, double b);` might be something like `template <typename A, typename B> class Foo; /*...*/ template <typename A, int B> class Foo;` since what changed is the (meta)type of the parameter.

Comment: @L.F. ‘typename A’ is a placeholder for a type rather than a variable name of formal parameter. You’re totally wrong. The compiler is right.

Comment: You mean VS is right and GCC and Clang are totally wrong?

Comment: Then how do you interpret the fact that the compiler rejects a in-scope type name `A` and accepts a never previously defined name `C`?

Comment: @L.F. I mean you are wrong and compiler is right. I didn’t say which compiler is better when addressing your error. ‘B’ in ‘typename B’ holds a type while ‘B’ in ‘int B’ is only a variable name. They’re totally different.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that one is a type while the other is a non-type entity. But this does not mean `A` and `C` are conflicting types.

Comment: @L.F. It may be a bug that the complier accept a undefined type C but that’s because your code has error on syntax.

Comment: So you mean even `template <typename A> class Foo; template <typename B> class Foo { };` is wrong?

Comment: This may deserve another question though.

Comment: @L.F. Yes, it’s wrong. You defined a type in your definition which is different from that in your declaration.

Comment: @L.F. ‘A’ in ‘typename A’ is a placeholder for a type but ‘A’ is not a concrete type, so compiler won’t compare the type of actual argument with the type defined in your declaration.But compiler will see your definition when running the function. So in your example the compiler accept the undefined type C which is actually defined in your definition. After all, it’s impossible for compilers to report ALL of mistakes in code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that the compiler was fooled by my ill-formed declarations and did not manage to diagnose the bug? That's even worse than I ever thought :P

Comment: @L.F. Yes, the compiler didn’t manage to diagnose the bug. :P

Comment: Thank you for all your attention and explanation. I will do further research :)